# What packages in a systemd distro rely on it?

Tags: systemd, init

I am aware that the reason you can't install runit or openrc on a distro and expect it to work is that some packages and stuff rely on systemd. What exactly do they rely on? The `systemctl` command? What is systemd-specific here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, the desktop environments require the component activation logic provided by dbus, which now pretty much requires systemd, and there are a few features that depend on having a declarative configuration interface to activate and deactivate features.

For example, having a dropdown button that lets the user select whether the machine suspends, hibernates or ignores it when the user closes the lid requires systemd-logind, because it is the only existing implementation that has a corresponding setting.

The traditional Unix daemons largely don't care whether they are started from systemd and usually don't profit much from it.

Comment: oh ok, thank you!

Comment: Nitpick: elogind also provides the same power management options that systemd-logind does, so that hypothetical example is not really accurate.